# Eclipse @Deprecated yields syntax error

Tags: java, eclipse

This seems like a simple question that I cannot find the answer to when googling.

The `@Deprecated` tag is giving me a syntax error in eclipse.

**Error**:

> Deprecated cannot be resolved to a type

Am I missing an import or something?

**Edit**:  Using Eclipse Juno

Comment: it's in java.lang so you shouldn't need an import

Comment: It appears as though it is spelled correctly here.  Is it spelled correctly on your machine?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Yes, it is spelled the same way in the post as it is on my machine.

Comment: It was introduced in Java 1.5.  Are you using an earlier version of Java?  1.3 or 1.4?

Comment: @MikeClark: Annotations were also introduced in Java 1.5.  I imagine that pre-Java 1.5 compilers would choke on the `@` symbol before they got as far as `Deprecated`.

Comment: @MikeClark I am using version 1.6

Comment: Maybe you have set bootclasspath?

Comment: Can you try a refresh on your project? (F5). Also, Clean, Build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to reproduce this error:

1. Create a project with as run time `jdk5` or higher.
2. Right click on that project and go to `Build Path > Configure Build Path...`
3. Go to the `Libraries` tab, remove the actual JRE System Library (1.5 or higher) and then add JRE System Library 1.4 or lower. Click OK.

The project will rebuild and you'll get the error `Deprecated cannot be resolved to a type`

So you need to ckeck the setting under the `Libraries` tab and make sure you have a run time `1.5` or higher.

Answer (score 2):

YUou also need to make sure your compiler settings are configured to allow these 'new' features. Project->Properties and go to the Java Compiler section

[image: Project Settings]

Comment: changing the compiler compliance to 1.4 leads to the error `Syntax error, annotations are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater` and not the one described by OP

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.  Thank you to those who tried to help with comments.

The standard java library (JRE System Library) in the Java Build Path was incorrect.

I corrected this and the syntax error disappears.

Comment: I wish I had  seen your answer earlier, I even downloaded and installed a jdk1.4 to test it :S, you could [accept you own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16930/191550) btw!

Comment: I prefer your answer because you provide a means of reproducing the results. Useful.